# Info on Chanukah oil burning lengths

Tags: chanuka, time, how-to, menora-chanukia, oil

If I recall correctly, Chanukah lights must burn until at least 1/2 hour after nightfall (or after they are lit).

I know that different types of oil burn faster or slower. Would someone know if there is a chart or some other source, preferably on-line, that lists how quickly certain types of oil would burn? As an example, I have a lot of sesame oil and avocado oil around my home, and I'd like to use these instead of buying a huge bottle of olive oil. But, I'm uncertain if either of these other oils will burn long enough using my menorah's holder (I think it holds about 3-4 ounces.)

Comment: The rate is significantly dependent on the thickness of the wick.

Comment: Test it out now and you will know.

Comment: @GershonGold ineed: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/12/dont-be-afraid-to-use-the-science/